# Repeat X in seven rows before incrementing X

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Like so:

```
1
1
1    
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
...
```

Something like `=IF(A1=4,1,A1+1)` would work if the sequence wasn't all the same value.

Comment: Could you please provide a little bit more detail? Perhaps, edit your post above with an example of the outcome you are looking for.

Comment: @IrwinAllen13: "Like so" *is* the desired outcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for division:

```
=INT((ROW()-1)/7)
```

NOTE: You will have to play with the 1 and 7 in the formula above to adapt to your needs. -1 is like an offset, and 7 is the number of times for the repeat. Use -2 if the numbers should start on row 2 for example. Lastly, if you want to start with 1 instead of zero, simply add 1.

[image]

Comment: Just to give another option `=ROUNDUP(ROW()/7,0)` when you want to start with 1. Or `=ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/7,0)` when you want to start with a 0. :)

Answer (score 0):

`=(`*the previous row's value*`) + IF(`*the previous 7 rows all have the same value*`, 1, 0 )`

Obviously(?) this will not work for the first 7 rows; the first row could be the starting value, the next 6 just a straight copy of that.